# HDMI-CEC - control brightness

Tags: television, hdmi, hdmi-cec

is there any way to control TV brightness over HDMI CEC?

I built the TV into a frame and forgot to turn down the brightness...Any chance or would I have to unframe it in order to be able to use the remote?

Commands like `echo 'volup' | cec-client -s -d 1` work fine, but is there any way to control the brightness? Maybe by transfering specific bytes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
`echo h | cec-client -s -d 1`

Source: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/9147